# My Node js server exit with code 0 when the RabbitMq server goes down

Tags: node.js, express, rabbitmq

I have a audit Log server(Node js) which is subscribed to RabbitMQ server, When My RabbitMQ server goes down then in audit Log server the error handler for RabbitMQ broker is called three times and then the application exit with code 0. I am using docker for running this micro service application. I am using rascal client library for RabbitMQ connection.

Here is the error Message,

**npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 143

npm ERR! audit-service@1.0.0 start: `nodemon -L --ignore 'test*.js' src/index.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 143

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the audit-service@1.0.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR! /home/node/.npm/_logs/2023-06-08T05_37_14_936Z-debug.log**
**nexus-backend-audit-service-1 exited with code 0

nexus-backend-audit-service-1 exited with code 0**

Docker compose code audit service,

**audit-service:

build:

context: audit-service/

dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev

healthcheck:

test: curl -f http://localhost:6002/api/healthcheck || exit 1

interval: 10s

timeout: 10s

retries: 3

start_period: 30s

ports:

- 6002:6002

image: nexus-audit-service:latest

restart: on-failure

deploy:

resources:

limits:

cpus: ${AUDITSERVICE_RESOURCES_LIMITS_CPUS:-2}

memory: ${AUDITSERVICE_RESOURCES_LIMITS_MEMORY:-4G}

reservations:

cpus: ${AUDITSERVICE_RESOURCES_RESERVATIONS_CPUS:-1}

memory: ${AUDITSERVICE_RESOURCES_RESERVATIONS_MEMORY:-2G}

volumes:

- ./audit-service:/usr/src/app

networks:

- nexus-network

command: npm start**

I tried the locate the log file but was not able to find it.
I was expecting that even if the rabbitmq server goes down the
application should not exit with code 0

Comment: If you have access to the source code, check if you have handled the case where a connection to your MQTT server cannot be made, or when the number of retries has been exceeded